# tablesorter.js multiple textExtraction

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

Using tablesorter.js to sort table columns.

I have one column with images, so I used textExtraction to get image alt value to do sorting.

Now I want to use textExtraction to sort other columns with commas and currency symbols.

Independently, both will work but I am not able to get both of them working.

Tablesorter has an [example](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-option-text-extraction.html) that I am not able to adapt.

```
textExtraction: {
  0: function(node, table, cellIndex){ return $(node).find("strong").text(); },
  1: function(node, table, cellIndex){ return $(node).find("div").text(); },
  2: function(node, table, cellIndex){ return $(node).find("span").text(); },
  3: function(node, table, cellIndex){ return $(node).find("em").text(); },
  4: function(node, table, cellIndex){ return $(node).find("a").text(); },
  '.date' : function(node, table, cellIndex){ return $(node).find("u").text(); }
}
```

I modified my code as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function($){ 
    $("#cardSort").tablesorter(
        {
            initWidgets: true,

            textExtraction: {
                0: function(s){
                    if($(s).find('img').length == 0) return $(s).text();
                    return $(s).find('img').attr('alt');
                },
                1: function(s){
                    return $(s).text().replace(/[,$£€]/g,'');
                }                    
            }
        }
    );
}
);
```

This appears to be same as the tablesorter example eg it is using the numbered function method. But in this format neither work.

Any ideas on how to have both textExtraction functions?

Edit to add: this is TableSorter Version 2.0.5b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you might still be using the original version of tablesorter (v2.0.5)... setting the [`textExtraction`](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#textextraction) as an object doesn't work on that version, you'll need to use my [fork of tablesorter](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/).

---

Update: If you *must* use v2.0.5, then try the following:

```
textExtraction: function(node) {
  var $cell = $(node),
    text = $cell.text();
  switch(node.cellIndex) {
    case 0:
      return $cell.find('img').length ? $cell.find('img').attr('alt') : text;
    case 1:
      return text.replace(/[,$£€]/g,'');
    default:
      return text;
  }
}
```

Note: This method won't work as expected when there are `colspan`s within the `tbody`.

Comment: Yes, I didn't note the version, just updated question. It is TableSorter Version 2.0.5b

Comment: This just goes to default and returns text. What is the case looking for?

Comment: The `case` is using the `cellIndex` of the header cell... it's a zero-based index indicating the column; but as I mentioned it doesn't take `colspan` or `rowspan` into account.

Comment: Ok does the job. My table didn't have `colspan` or `rowspan`. I just updated case to refer to specific columns in my table.